# how to read Null values in HBase java

Tags: java, hadoop, nullpointerexception, hbase

Im trying to retrive Long values from HBase table. But it is giving NullPointerException while retriving Particular column family.

Sample Code snippet :

```
long total_size=0;
total_size +=Bytes.toLong(rr.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("size"),Bytes.toBytes("size"))));
```

I have stored values for size as long. some of the size vlaues are null. I want to retrive null values and assign them to "0" ZERO.

Please give me appropriate code snippet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Bytes.toLong()` method do not check whether the retrieved `byte[]` is `null` or not and call its `byte[].length` which will throw your exception. You can try the below work around :

```
String longValue = Bytes.toString(rr.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("size"),Bytes.toBytes("size")));
total_size += (longValue != null ? Bytes.toLong(rr.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("size"),Bytes.toBytes("size")):0l);
```

or

```
try{
  total_size +=Bytes.toLong(rr.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("size"),Bytes.toBytes("size"))));
}catch(NullPointerException e){
  // no need to increment total_size by 0
}
```

Comment: In the 1st approach, giving left hand side value as ascii char so assign to long type giving numberformat exception. 2nd Approach its giving null pointer exception.

Comment: did u get atleast one not null values from size column earlier? Also one thing, when you tried the 2nd approach you got Nullpointer exception every time?

Comment: In the first approach the longValue variable is String , I just used it to know whether 'size' column value is null or not. Please do not assign it to long as such. That is why i checked it for not null and if so I retrieve the long value from "size" column again.In this case u got Numberfomat exception , means you were not saving a "long" value in  "size" column. Please make sure this.